# Passing php count as json string along with json array

Tags: php, android, json, mysqli

I have the following data parser in my android studio project with which i successfully retrieve posts and related user information from mysql tables. My problem lies with getting likes count for each post from the likes table then passing the count value as a json string along with the array of the other post data.
Here is my working dataParser.java file

```
package com.blogy.posts.getter;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.blogy.R;
import com.blogy.posts.dataSetter.Spacecraft;
import com.blogy.posts.dataBinder.MyAdapter;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class DataParser extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean> {

Context c;
String jsonData;
RecyclerView rv;

ProgressDialog pd;
ArrayList<Spacecraft> spacecrafts=new ArrayList<>();

public DataParser(Context c, String jsonData, RecyclerView rv) {
    this.c = c;
    this.jsonData = jsonData;
    this.rv = rv;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    pd=new ProgressDialog(c);
    pd.setTitle("Parse");
    pd.setMessage("Parsing...Please wait");
    pd.show();
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    return this.parseData();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean parsed) {
    super.onPostExecute(parsed);

    pd.dismiss();

    if(parsed)
    {
        //BIND
        MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(c,spacecrafts);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);


    }else {
        Toast.makeText(c, R.string.cantretrieveposts,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}

private Boolean parseData()
{
    try
    {
        JSONArray ja=new JSONArray(jsonData);
        JSONObject jo;

        spacecrafts.clear();
        Spacecraft spacecraft;

        for (int i=0;i<ja.length();i++)
        {
            jo=ja.getJSONObject(i);

            String id=jo.getString("id");
            String imageUrl=jo.getString("profile_image");
            String firstname=jo.getString("first_name");
            String lastname=jo.getString("last_name");
            String createdat=jo.getString("created_at");
            String body=jo.getString("body");

            spacecraft=new Spacecraft();

            spacecraft.setId(id);
            spacecraft.setImageUrl(avatarUrl);
            spacecraft.setFirstname(firstname);
            spacecraft.setLastname(lastname);
            spacecraft.setCreatedat(createdat);
            spacecraft.setBody(body);

            spacecrafts.add(spacecraft);


        }

        return true;


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}

}
```

and here is my working postGetter.php script

```
<?php

require_once 'include/Config.php';
    // connecting to mysql
    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or 
die(mysqli_error());
    // selecting database
    mysqli_select_db($con, DB_DATABASE) or die(mysqli_error());


$sql="SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN posts ON (posts.user_id = users.id)";


$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if($result)
{
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
            $data[]=$row;
    }

    print(json_encode($data));
}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

I'd be grateful for any pointers on how to get past any step.Thanks

Comment: Hard to tell with the information you are showing, but I would guess something like `LEFT JOIN`-ing on the likes table and a `GROUP BY` the posts id, which gives you the count.

Comment: you mean joining all three tables?